# asp.net page not returning ajax request

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am attempting to send an AJAX request from an ASP.NET Gridview row. Each row in the gridview shows completed jobs. Some jobs have files that can be downloaded. The end goal here is to show the download urls in a colorbox overlay, but I am having trouble just returning the list of files to the base page now. To show that there are files to download from an order I unhide a button control in the order number column. Javascript on the page follows.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=gvMessenger.ClientID%> input").filter(":not(:has(table, th))").click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
         var $cell = $(e.target).closest("td");
        //$("#<%=gvMessenger.ClientID%> td").removeClass("highlight"); $cell.addClass("highlight"); $("#message").text('You have selected: ' + $cell.text());
        $("#Message").html("");

        var orderID = $cell.text()
        orderID = $.trim(orderID);
        sendData(orderID);
        function sendData(orderID) {
            var loc = window.location.href;
            loc = (loc.substr(loc.length - 1, 1) == "/") ?
            loc + "CompletedOrdersNew.aspx" : loc;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: loc + "/GetFiles",
                data: "{'orderID':'" + orderID + "'}",
                contentType: "application/jason; charset=utf-8",
                datatype: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    $("ContentArea").html(msg.d);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("An error occured in getting your files.");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The function in the page codebehind that should fire on the ajax request follows.

```
    <WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function GetFiles(ByRef orderID As Integer) As String
    Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    Dim dt As DataTable
    dt = Dac.ExecuteDataTable("GetS3Files", Parameter("@OrderID", orderID))
    Dim arrr(dt.Rows.Count) As Object

    For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        arrr(i) = dt.Rows(i).ItemArray
    Next

    Dim json As New JavaScriptSerializer
    Return json.Serialize(dict)

End Function
```

When watching the page in FireBug I see the request go out to the GetFiles function with the orderID number {'orderID':'10000315'}

```
POST http://localhost:57210/AMSSite/Customer/CompletedOrdersNew.aspx/GetFiles
```

But the call does not fire the GetFiles function and the response I am getting is the page html.

Not sure what is going on here.

Answer (score 1):

Try sending `orderID` as a number since you webmethod expects an int, also in JSON keys and strings are quoted with double quotes(`"`)

```
data: "{\"orderID\":" + orderID + "}",
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction on the number format. I made the suggested corrections but am still not firing the function GetFiles and am getting the page html back as my response. The orderID is now being sent as a number.

Answer (score 1):

You made a typo in `contentType` option. Should be: `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`

Comment: Thank you for that. I have a friend named Jason so do that quite often. Now I get a server error message Cannot convert object of type \u0027System.Int32\u0027 to type \u0027System.Int32&\u0027" Not quite sure what it is telling me. After looking on the net a bit it seems to indicate that ASP.NET does not like my input variables. Do you see a problem there?

Comment: I seem to have a problem with the json formating now. The issue seems to with converting from what is recieved at the server to what asp.net wants to process in a webmethod. The error is "Cannot convert object of type \u0027System.String\u0027 to type \u0027System.String&\u0027" I change the input parameter in my function to string to see if that helped. It didn't.

Comment: Aside from my misspelling the issue here was that my WebMethod function was ByRef. It should be ByVal. After banging my head against the wall and reading some great stuff on javascript and json services I found the real answer at http://projectsmm.com/technet/asp/index.shtml. VB.Net by default sets function variables to ByRef. For some reason .NET web services don't accept this.

Hope this helps some one else. The same type of question seems to be common.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my question for the sake of any other VB.NET/ASP.NET folks running into this problem. Aside from my misspelling the issue here was that my WebMethod function was ByRef. It needs to be **BYVAL**. After banging my head against the wall and reading some great stuff on javascript and json services I found the real answer at http://projectsmm.com/technet/asp/index.shtml. VB.Net by default sets function variables to ByRef. For some reason .NET web services don't accept this. Change to ByVal and it works.

Hope this helps some one else not spend the hours I looked at this.